# Relational Algebra: Select tuples based on whether an attribute is unique in a table

Tags: relational-algebra

Given a table:

```
T = {A1, A2, A3, A4}
```

How do you write a relational algebra statement that picks all tuples that have the same value for A3 as another tuple in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a equijoin with T and itself on column A3.

T2←T,T⋈<sub>T.A3=T2.A3</sub> T2

Now any tuple from T will be connected with all tuples that have the same value for A3. You can further select for a specific value of A3 from T and project to the attributes from T2.